# Customizing serialization of System.Text.Json without converter?

Tags: c#, serialization, system.text.json

Let's say I have a type/class "Person" and I would like to write custom serialization for it. Typical answer to this problem would be "write a converter". The thing is, I don't want to go this route -- I would like to write serialization directly into this type "Person", so this class would know how to serialize itself.

How to do it when using System.Text.JSON?

Comment: _"write serialization directly into this type"_ What does this mean? Can you show an example?

Comment: @shingo, I cannot give an example, because example would be the answer (which I don't know). But maybe I rephrase, Person+converter make two types right? I would like to have one type -- Person (which would be "converter" at the same time). With Newtonsoft it was easy, but ISerializable is banned in System.Text.JSON, see https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/54940 and I am looking for another approach but the same principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're fighting against the API design here; a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/handle-overflow) is going to be the easiest way to take control of your type's serialization.  That being said, if for some reason you refuse to write a converter, you could customize your JSON serialization by populating a [`JsonExtensionDataAttribute` overflow dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/handle-overflow) with your customized JSON contents during serialization via an [`OnSerializing`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.ijsononserializing?view=net-6.0) callback, then postprocess the overflow dictionary to populate your model via an [`OnDeserialized`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.ijsonondeserialized?view=net-6.0) callback.  You will also need to prevent default serialization by applying [`[JsonIgnore]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute) to all properties that should not be serialized automatically.

For instance, say you have the following model:

```
public class Model 
{
    public List<string?>? List { get; set; }
}
```

And you want it to be serialized like so:

```json
{
  "0": "value 0",
  "1": "value 1"
}
```

Then you could define your model as follows:

```
public class Model : IJsonOnDeserialized, IJsonOnSerializing, IJsonOnSerialized
{
    [JsonIgnore] // Prevent default serialization of properties that are serialized as part of the JsonExtensionData dictionary
    public List<string?>? List { get; set; }
    
    [JsonExtensionData, JsonInclude]
    public Dictionary<string, JsonElement>? Elements { get; private set; }

    protected virtual Dictionary<string, JsonElement> SerializeJsonElements(Dictionary<string, JsonElement> elements) => 
        List.EmptyIfNull().Select((value, index) => (value, index)).Aggregate(elements, (e, p) => { e.Add(p.index.ToInvariantString(), p.value.ToJsonElement()); return e; } );

    protected virtual void DeserializeJsonElements(Dictionary<string, JsonElement>? elements) => 
        List = elements?.Select(p => p.Value.Deserialize<string>()).ToList();

    void IJsonOnSerializing.OnSerializing() => Elements = SerializeJsonElements(new ());
    void IJsonOnSerialized.OnSerialized() => Elements = null; // Elements are no longer needed, so null them out.
    void IJsonOnDeserialized.OnDeserialized() 
    {
        DeserializeJsonElements(Elements);
        Elements = null;
    }
}

public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> EmptyIfNull<T>([System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.AllowNull] this IEnumerable<T> enumerable) => enumerable ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    public static JsonElement ToJsonElement<T>(this T value, JsonSerializerOptions? options = default) => JsonSerializer.SerializeToElement(value, options);
    public static string ToInvariantString<TFormattable>(this TFormattable input) where TFormattable : IFormattable => Convert.ToString(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ?? "";
}
```

Then it will be serialized as required.  Notes:

- The `JsonExtensionData` dictionary must be public, but may have a private setter if also marked with [`[JsonInclude]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/immutability?pivots=dotnet-6-0#non-public-property-accessors).
- The dictionary is nulled out in the `OnDeserialized` callback as well as in an [`OnSerialized`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.ijsononserialized?view=net-6.0) callback to prevent it from permanently consuming memory.  (Thus this trick requires the implementation of three interfaces: `IJsonOnSerializing`, `IJsonOnSerialized` and `IJsonOnDeserialized`.)
- Derived types may add their own content to the dictionary of custom elements by overriding `SerializeJsonElements()` and `DeserializeJsonElements()`.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IkTVMx).

As an aside, I would question your assumption that writing a converter is difficult or adds complexity to your library.  The converter can be a private, [nested type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types) inside your type as long as you apply it direct to the type via [`[JsonConverter(typeof(TMyType.TInnerConverter))`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverterattribute?view=net-6.0).  For instance, here's a private converter for the `Model` type above:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(Model.ModelConverter))]
public class Model 
{
    public List<string?>? List { get; set; }

    private class ModelConverter : JsonConverter<Model>
    {
        public override Model? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            new Model { List = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string?>>(ref reader, options)?.Values.ToList() };

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Model value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => 
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value.List.EmptyIfNull().Select((value, index) => (value, index)).ToDictionary(p => p.index.ToInvariantString(), p => p.value));
    }
}

public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> EmptyIfNull<T>([System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.AllowNull] this IEnumerable<T> enumerable) => enumerable ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    public static string ToInvariantString<TFormattable>(this TFormattable input) where TFormattable : IFormattable => Convert.ToString(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ?? "";
}
```

I think this is simpler than the `JsonExtensionData` workaround, and adds no complexity to the public surface of your types.

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IGP264).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not pretty sure whether if this is what you want. `SerializationInfo` is just some kinda K-V collection, so if an object implemements any enumerable like `IDictionary` or `IDictionary<,>`, the default converter will serialize it as a json object.

You can declare an interface to reduce unrelated methods that have to be implemented in the class

```
interface IJsonObject : IDictionary
{
    int ICollection.Count => 0;
    ICollection IDictionary.Keys => null;
    //...
}

class Person : IJsonObject
{
    // data example
    Dictionary<string, object> properties = new()
    {
        ["a"] = 100,
        ["b"] = "Big"
    };

    IDictionaryEnumerator IDictionary.GetEnumerator()
       => properties.GetEnumerator();  
}
```

Result:

```
{"a":100,"b":"Big"}
```

Comment: This is pretty clever approach, thank you. However it has also high cost -- polluting pretty tiny types with all `IDictionary` methods.Implementing `IEnumerable` does not bring any extra methods but it does not work -- it is no longer object in JSON, but an array.

Comment: Benefit from default interface implementation, you don't have to add all these methods in your class.